# Retrieving data from firebase database and displaying in Navigation drawer header in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I retrieve a user profile information from firebase database and display it in a Navigation drawer header?

```
     @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Map<String, String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
           String firstname = map.get("firstname");
           String lastname = map.get("lastname");
           String phone = map.get("phone");

           Log.v("E_VALUE", "firstname : " + firstname);
           Log.v("E_VALUE", "lastname : " + lastname);
           Log.v("E_VALUE", "phone : " + phone);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });

}
```